# NopCommerce Add and Update bulk Products with Complete Information

Tags: configuration, e-commerce, nopcommerce

I want to Add and Update Products in Bulk, not only the basic information but also related product, cross sell, etc., I did check the excel functionality but it doesn't has the option of adding the Complete Information

I Looked at the nopcommerce API, but Currently it doesn't have the option of adding Products through API,My Questions are :

1) I want to know what is the Other Best Way of adding Products  , please elaborate what is the best Way of Achieving it

2) I tried to create a plugin of It through its Source Code (I Downloaded Source Code Separately), and plugin was Successfully created in Source, How can I add it in my existing NopCommerce Website which is without Source Code

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the second question: to add created plugin in your existing site you should

- build your plugin
- find it's folder in the Nop.Web\Plugins in your source code
- copy it into the Plugins folder in your NoSource project